# JGroups ec2 cluster fails to connect (times out) with Hibernate Search / Infinispan setup

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, hibernate-search, infinispan, jgroups

I'm trying to set up a distributed Hibernate Search (5.5.4) cluster on my Elastic Beanstalk (Tomcat8) environment, using Infinispan (8.2.4) and JGroups.

I'm currently stuck on an issue where a node can't connect to an existing cluster, and it times out trying to connect.

```
Starting JGroups channel ISPN
variable "${jgroups.s3.pre_signed_delete_url}" in S3_PING could not be substituted; pre_signed_delete_url is removed from properties
variable "${jgroups.s3.prefix}" in S3_PING could not be substituted; prefix is removed from properties
variable "${jgroups.s3.pre_signed_put_url}" in S3_PING could not be substituted; pre_signed_put_url is removed from properties
ip-172-31-24-216-1799: JOIN(ip-172-31-24-216-1799) sent to ip-172-31-14-33-238 timed out (after 5000 ms), on try 1
ip-172-31-24-216-1799: JOIN(ip-172-31-24-216-1799) sent to ip-172-31-14-33-238 timed out (after 5000 ms), on try 2
...
ip-172-31-24-216-1799: JOIN(ip-172-31-24-216-1799) sent to ip-172-31-14-33-238 timed out (after 5000 ms), on try 10
ip-172-31-24-216-1799: too many JOIN attempts (10): becoming singleton
ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ISPN: [ip-172-31-24-216-Channel ISPN local address is ip-172-31-24-216-1799, physical addresses are [127.0.0.1:7800]
```

I have enabled all types of inbound traffic within the elastic beanstalk security group, and can successfully ping the other nodes in the group using the internal IP addresses.

This is my infinispan.xml file

```xml
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:8.2 http://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-8.2.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:8.2">

    <jgroups>
        <stack-file name="default-jgroups-ec2" path="default-configs/default-jgroups-ec2.xml"/>
    </jgroups>

    <cache-container name="HibernateSearch" default-cache="default" statistics="false" shutdown-hook="DONT_REGISTER">

        <transport stack="default-jgroups-ec2"/>

        <!-- Duplicate domains are allowed so that multiple deployments with default configuration
            of Hibernate Search applications work - if possible it would be better to use JNDI to share
            the CacheManager across applications -->
        <jmx duplicate-domains="true"/>

        <!-- *************************************** -->
        <!--  Cache to store Lucene's file metadata  -->
        <!-- *************************************** -->
        <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesMetadata" mode="SYNC" remote-timeout="25000">          
            <locking striping="false" acquire-timeout="10000" concurrency-level="500" write-skew="false"/>
            <transaction mode="NONE"/>
            <eviction max-entries="-1" strategy="NONE"/>
            <expiration max-idle="-1"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store path="LuceneIndexes/Metadata" preload="true" />
            </persistence>
            <indexing index="NONE"/>
            <state-transfer enabled="true" timeout="480000" await-initial-transfer="true"/>
        </replicated-cache>

        <!-- **************************** -->
        <!--  Cache to store Lucene data  -->
        <!-- **************************** -->
        <distributed-cache name="LuceneIndexesData" mode="SYNC" remote-timeout="25000">
            <locking striping="false" acquire-timeout="10000" concurrency-level="500" write-skew="false"/>
            <transaction mode="NONE"/>
            <eviction max-entries="-1" strategy="NONE"/>
            <expiration max-idle="-1"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store path="LuceneIndexes/Data" />
            </persistence>
            <indexing index="NONE"/>
            <state-transfer enabled="true" timeout="480000" await-initial-transfer="true"/>
        </distributed-cache>

        <!-- ***************************** -->
        <!--  Cache to store Lucene locks  -->
        <!-- ***************************** -->
        <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesLocking" mode="SYNC" remote-timeout="25000">
            <locking striping="false" acquire-timeout="10000" concurrency-level="500" write-skew="false"/>
            <transaction mode="NONE"/>
            <eviction max-entries="-1" strategy="NONE"/>   
            <expiration max-idle="-1"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store path="LuceneIndexes/Locking" />
            </persistence>
            <indexing index="NONE"/>
            <state-transfer enabled="true" timeout="480000" await-initial-transfer="true"/>
        </replicated-cache>
    </cache-container>

</infinispan>
```

And the jgroups config file is the default ec2 config packaged with Infinispan [default-jgroups-ec2.xml](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/master/cloud/src/main/resources/default-configs/default-jgroups-ec2.xml)

Does anyone have any idea of where I may have gone wrong, or what exactly I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your local address is 127.0.0.1:7800, which is the default. This will definitely not work if you need to talk to other nodes.

Comment: thanks, I haven't had a chance to test anything out yet, but I'm assuming it's the default bind_addr in default-jgroups-ec2.xml value you're talking about. I will try fetching the private IP using EC2MetadataUtils, and setting the "jgroups.tcp.address" system property

Comment: I haven't had a chance to play with EC2, but maybe extracting the IP address using `hostname -i` and passing it to the application would be sufficient.

Comment: If you know what type of IP addresses EC2 allocates, you could use `bind_addr=match-address:192.168.*` which binds to any address that starts with 192.168. See http://www.jgroups.org/manual/index.html#protlist  for details

Comment: thanks @BelaBan, I've now got it working. As per above I'm using EC2MetadataUtils from the AWS java API to get the private IP and set it as a system property ("jgroups.tcp.address") during my application initialisation phase (before hibernate search initialises). I think this is the most robust option as the IP block could change or differ between regions, and passing it to the application as a parameter on start up would require some trickery with the elastic beanstalk startup process

Answer (score 0):

Also you can see those messages in the logs:

```
variable "${jgroups.s3.pre_signed_delete_url}" in S3_PING could not be substituted; pre_signed_delete_url is removed from properties
variable "${jgroups.s3.prefix}" in S3_PING could not be substituted; prefix is removed from properties
variable "${jgroups.s3.pre_signed_put_url}" in S3_PING could not be substituted; pre_signed_put_url is removed from properties
```

You should probably define those variables.

Comment: Thanks, but these are optional values not required when I have set the location for the s3 bucket. Currently not having issues reading/writing from s3, just with the nodes connecting to each other